# ngClick and ngDisabled on templated anchor tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on the following directive:

```
module.directive('myButton', function () {
    var directive = {
        compile: compile,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            click: '&',
            disabled: '@'
        },
        template: '<a class="my-button my-button-{{type}}" data-ng-click="disabled || click()"><ng-transclude /></a>',
        transclude: true
    };

    function compile(element, attributes) {
        if (typeof attributes.click == 'undefined') attributes.click = function () { };
        if (typeof attributes.disabled== 'undefined') attributes.disabled = false;
    }

    return directive;
});
```

And I'm got some dummies on a page that look like this:

```
<my-button type="1a" click="alert('Button 1a works!')" disabled="false">Test A</my-button>
```

I can't seem to get the click and disabled functions of the button working (at least not at the same time). I've styled the anchor tag so it looks like a button. Anchor tags aren't affected by the `disabled` attribute, so the `ngClick` has to check if it should fire.

How can I get the click and disabled functionalities to work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `disabled: '@'` to `disabled: '='`.

Read-only parameters (`'@'`) are passed in as strings regardless of the type of the variable assigned to the parameter. You want to use a boolean; a two-way parameter (`'='`) persists the type.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by having `&&` condition over it instead of `||`. Basically if disabled flag is `true` then `ng-click` expression would not evaluate further. If its false then will call `click` method. Look at attached plunkr example.

```
data-ng-click="!disabled && click()"
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zwfq8wiyIv8fgwNT3XdQ?p=preview)

Comment: Your example doesn't use a directive. Could you augment it to more closely resemble my issue? And why would `&&` work but not `||`?

Comment: @ricksmt haven't you looked at plunkr?

Comment: Yes. You don't use a directive, just a controller and the default scope.